# Can I use GDPR to read an Airbnb review about me before I post mine?

Tags: gdpr

I just had a bad experience with Airbnb. The circumstances would be too long to describe and not relevant to my question. The fact is that I just have had an email that the host (I am the guest) let me a review and that I can read it after I post mine. I am considering, but reluctant, to make a GDPR access request to access it (before I post mine). This review, whatever it is, seems to clearly be a personal information that Airbnb have on me. Would I have the right to do it? Has something similar already tried? I am EU consumer residing in the UE. If the comment appear to be bad. Could I, under the GDPR, ask for it to be removed?

Comment: The review is not your personal information. It's what another Airbnb user has to say about you. How would GDPR give you right over someone else's commentary?

Comment: What makes you think you would still have any ability or right to submit your own review if you forced AirBnB to hand over the other parties review (by whatever means)?  You certainly might be able to use a Subject Access Request to gain access to the other parties review, but I think you might not like the repercussions of attempting to circumvent a legitimate process.

Comment: @Consis. https://gdpr-info.eu/issues/personal-data/ . I quote "Personal data are any information which are related to an identified or identifiable natural person." Someone else commentary seems to obviously fall into this category.

Comment: @Moo This is my first airbnb experience and it was bad. I agree that I may not like the consequences of doing a subject access request. However exercising a right under a democratically voted law can never be considered as circumventing a legitimate process. Laws have to take this into consideration.

Comment: Regarding the removal, you will likely not succeed if you base it on the GDPR, because airbnb wil probably consider the data processing of the comments as a legitimate interest for future hosts. However, if the comment contains untrue statements, you can base the removal request on defamation. But you must be able to prove it.

Comment: On the other hand airbnb itself mention the possibility of deleting the account https://www.airbnb.com/help/article/240/how-do-i-deactivate-or-delete-my-account. It also state that "You'll need to set up a new account if you want to use Airbnb again.". At least in my case (first airbnb experienec that was bad), it seems that it would achieve it.

Comment: @olivier "However exercising a right under a democratically voted law can never be considered as circumventing a legitimate process" - I'm not sure that gives you carte blanche to go around established procedures with no recourse. The service provider may be required to fulfill a request under the GDPR, but they don't have to treat you indifferently afterward. As for closing accounts and reopening them, do that often enough to evade bad feedback and the service provider can permanently ban you - and hold enough info about you under Legitimate Interest to enforce that ban.

Comment: @Moo my particular case is now over (all was in the end better than expected). But it seems we disagree on the fund of the problem. Established procedure, or the right to ban someone acting badly cannot be used to circumvent a democratic right given by a democratically voted law. Otherwise it is the end of the rule of law. You can keep a banlist for legitimate purpose. Exercising your democratic right cannot be seen as a legitimate reason to be on a banlist.

Comment: @olivier "Established procedure, or the right to ban someone acting badly cannot be used to circumvent a democratic right given by a democratically voted law" got any legal citations for that?  Theres nothing in the GDPR which prevents it.  You can cling to that belief all you want, but it's going to end in tears if you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personal data is any information relating to an identifiable person. The review relates to you, so you are the data subject and have a right to access. Airbnb is not required to provide this information through their normal procedures (e.g. their website interface), but would have to produce this information in response to a data subject request.

An alternative standpoint is that the review is not information, but just some document. The GDPR cannot be used as a dragnet to get access to all documents that happen to mention you.

Whereas your right to access is pretty absolute, your right to erasure is not. It only applies under comparatively narrow circumstances. You cannot use the GDPR to censor what other people say about you. Even if you delete your entire account, Airbnb might argue that they have an overriding legitimate interest to keep the review on file, in case you try evading bad reviews by starting a new account.

Also note that the GDPR gives the data controller one month to respond to any requests, which can be extended to two months. This might be longer than the time frame Airbnb gives you to write your review.

Comment: This answer most of my question. There is also a "right to be forgotten". https://gdpr.eu/right-to-be-forgotten/ . However the exemptions are so vague that it can be interpreted to mean anything. Do you know if there are precedent about it?

Comment: @olivier The GDPR right to erasure implements/encodes the right to be forgotten, so that the two are effectively synonymous. Here, Art 17(1)(c) might require erasure when “the data subject objects to the processing pursuant to Article 21(1) and there are no overriding legitimate grounds for the processing, or the data subject objects to the processing pursuant to Article 21(2)”. Art 21(2) doesn't apply because it's about marketing, and as hinted at in my answer there are likely to be overriding legitimate grounds to keep the review.

Comment: I would be interested to see a precedent about "this right to be forgotten" because any entity that holds information could always said they have a "legitimate" reason. I would be interested to see some cases where an actual judge have granted / refused a "right to be forgotten". Of course it is much broader than a review on airbnb, it could be any article / post, etc that someone made about you somewhere.

Comment: @olivier The GDPR is still young, so there's no such precedent. You are right that a data controller could always find such legitimate grounds, but if a data subjects thinks the controller did this incorrectly they can lodge a complaint with the data protection authority, or sue directly. There are pre-GDPR cases regarding the right to be forgotten, e.g. those that forced Google to remove certain search results.

Comment: I am not on a banlist, but many people here seems to think that it is legitimate to keep a banlist at the discretion of some big corporations. In Europe, in most countries, even a criminal record get usually cleared after a few years (except maybe for the most serious crime). That let me think that to be banned for life seems exaggerate and not "legitimate" if you only have violated an agreement without committing serious crime. But apparently there is no precedent. I understand that a temporary ban proportional to what you have done would probably be fine.

Comment: @olivier I'm not talking about bans, I'm just pointing out that you don't always have a right to erase your data. Whether a legitimate interest is really legitimate has to be weighed against your rights. Keeping data for a short duration (e.g. one year) is more likely to be compliant than keeping it for an unspecified duration.